# Node Express js Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, express-validator

I am new for node js. I am trying to insert the data to database, before that I did some validation for checking username already exist in database. Please see the coding which is used by me.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var models = require("../models");

const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('respond with a resource - merchant');
});

/* POST ADD USERS. */
router.post('/add-merchant', [
    check('name').not().isEmpty(),
], (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.json({ errors: errors.array()});
        }

        console.log("error passed")

        models.merchants.findOne({ where: {name: req.body.name}}).then((merchant) => {
            if(merchant) {
               throw new Error("Username already exists")
            }
            models.merchants.create(req.body).then((merchant) => {
                res.json(merchant)
            });
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({"status": "error", "message": error.message})
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am getting below error while running the above code

```
Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at models.merchants.create.then (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/routes/merchant.js:33:21)
    at tryCatcher (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/assistanz/Desktop/node/gb360/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

Please help anyone to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems because res.send() called more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs because you return the response and something is remain to load
you have to remove `console.log("error passed")` or you can put it before return statement..
and write `return` statement for every `res.json` statement
as

```
   return res.json({})
```

Comment: @Nishar Thanks for you reply. I am trying like this throw new Error("Username already exists"). This is also not working. Is this correct?

Comment: current error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client its occur because you are returning something to client but your code return else before execute that code

Comment: Now you can please add seperate condition for each return statement like if else..thank you

Answer (score 0):

HTTP uses a cycle that requires one response per request. When the client sends a request the server should send only one response back to client. So modify the code as below,

```
models.merchants.findOne({ where: { name: req.body.name } }).then((merchant) => {
    if (merchant) {
        throw new Error("Username already exists")
    } else {
        models.merchants.create(req.body).then((merchant) => {
            res.json(merchant)
        });
    }
})
```